# How to import data from seperate file beyond bundled app on frontend (Data from file)

Tags: javascript, webpack, deployment, frontend, bundler

I going to start developing an App, and I thinking, how could I made seperate file, to hold inside of them some kind of Data / Constants.
The purpose for this is that later on some other person will maintain it and he's not a programmer.
Ok, lets say that we have list of post in file `post.json`

```
Post = [
  {
     title: "first",
     body: "simple body"
  },
  {
     title: "Second",
     body: "Smth diff"
  }
]
```

And somewhere in the App there will becreated list of those posts using this `post.json`

And for future reason that List should be editable, by just editing file `post.json` and replacing old one with new.

It will be simple app (some kind of about me app) 3/4 views with routing, just frontend, but it should be easy maintainable.

I was thinking about React / Vue +SASS, as a part of practice but Could be anything with some bundler or even HTML template engine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that I wasnt smart at all,
all i need here is to add 
`post.json` as a `.js` file in the end of HTML file same as bundle is added in React or any any frontend framework

for example

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <scritp src="post.js"></script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

and when we will `console.log(Post)` our object will appear as a global object